# select from SQL table with concatenation of two string columns

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

### Issue

---

I want to write a query that will select all from a table where my string value is equal to two columns concatenated together.

This is plain English version:

```
@MYSTRING varchar(50)

SELECT ALL FROM [FFLOCNP] WHERE COLUMN1 + COLUMN2 = @MYSTRING
```

I have tried to use the COALESCE but i have never used this before and it is returning me an error:

```
@CODE varchar(50)

SELECT * FROM [dbo].[FFLOCNP] WHERE COALESCE([LOCTRY], '') || COALESCE([LOCLCN], '') = @CODE
```

Comment: SELECT * FROM [dbo].[FFLOCNP] WHERE COALESCE([LOCTRY], '')  + COALESCE([LOCLCN], '') = @CODE

Comment: If you are using SQL Server, I think it's better to use `ISNULL(COLUMN1,'')+ISNULL(COLUMN2,'') = @MYSTRING`

Comment: What kind of content in `@MYSTRING`,`COLUMN1 + COLUMN2` ??

Comment: @vitalygolub Thanks this has worked perfectly :D

Answer (score 0):

you have to use ISNULL for this. 
Use below query may be it helps you.

```
SELECT * FROM [FFLOCNP] WHERE ISNULL(COLUMN1,'') + ISNULL(COLUMN2,'') = @MYSTRING
```

Answer (score 0):

Be careful, when using ISNULL instead of COALESCE. ISNULL limits the returned value to the datatype of the first input parameter. In the given example column V1 will be implicitly defined with nvarchar(1), because the longest text in column V1 consists of only one character. ISNULL(V1, [param2]) will therefor return always a one character long string, regardless of the length of the second parameter. In your case ISNULL would work, if you wanted to replace a NULL with an empty string. If you wanted to replace a NULL with a longer string then you MUST use COALESCE instead of ISNULL. COALESCE returns the full string in parameter 2 regardless of the datatype of parameter 1. Apart from this COALESCE is standard SQL whereas ISNULL is a flavor of SQL-Server. Standard SQL should be preferred to T-SQL flavor to get more portable code.

```
WITH CTE_SRC AS
(
   SELECT
       [V1]
      ,[V2]
   FROM
      (VALUES  
          (N'A', N'BB')
         ,(NULL, N'BB')
         ,(N'A', NULL)
      ) T([V1],[V2])
)
SELECT 
    ISNULL([V1], '1234')  AS [ISNULL]
   ,COALESCE([V1], '123') AS [COALESCE] 
FROM 
   CTE_SRC

Result

ISNULL COALESCE
------ --------
A      A
1      123
A      A
```